# Обработка данных от VK API php

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Всем привет. Не могу получить массив в php из возвращенного JSON'а от VK API. Есть следующий ответ:

```
string(384) "{"response":{"upload_url":"https:\/\/pu.vk.com\/c841520\/upload.php?_query=eyJhY3QiOiJvd25lcl9jb3ZlciIsIm9pZCI6LTE0ODEzNTU0NSwiYXBpIjp0cnVlLCJhcGlfd3JhcCI6eyJoYXNoIjoiNzI5MjZlNTNhODJmMmRjMTBmIiwicGhvdG8iOiJ7cmVzdWx0fSJ9LCJtaWQiOjQ2OTQ3NDc1LCJzZXJ2ZXIiOjg0MTUyMCwiX29yaWdpbiI6Imh0dHBzOlwvXC9hcGkudmsuY29tIiwiX3NpZyI6ImQ5ZjQzNjU1NmEyY2ZhOTY0NTU4MzU5YjUwZTBkYzYyIn0&_crop=0,0,1490,400"}}"
```

Проблема в том, что делая `json_decode`, получаю вот такое чудо:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["response"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["upload_url"]=> string(350) "https://pu.vk.com/c841520/upload.php?_query=eyJhY3QiOiJvd25lcl9jb3ZlciIsIm9pZCI6LTE0ODEzNTU0NSwiYXBpIjp0cnVlLCJhcGlfd3JhcCI6eyJoYXNoIjoiNzI5MjZlNTNhOasdasdasdasddG8iOiJ7cmVzdWx0fSJ9LCJtaWQiOjQ2OTQ3NDc1LCJzZXJ2ZXIiOjg0MTUyMCwiX29yaWdpbiI6Imh0dHBzOlwvXC9hcGkudmsuY29tIiwiX3NpZyI6ImQ5ZjQzNjU1NmEyY2ZhOTY0NTU4MzU5YjUwZTBkYzYyIn0&_crop=0,0,1490,400" } }
```

Что с этим делать? Как из первого получить массив php?

Comment: если не умеешь в объекты, тогда используй `json_decode($json, true);`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да, только что заметил, что не поставил флаг